# Retrieve top 1 and 2 records from each group from table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that needs to get the first and second highest sku in each members wishlist. The below query works, but it takes way too long because there's about 9 million users and each user has about 10 wishlist items, so you can see that the query below will never finish.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN wl.rank = 1 THEN wl.SKU ELSE NULL END) AS [highestSku],
       MAX(CASE WHEN wl.rank = 2 THEN wl.SKU ELSE NULL END) AS [secondHighestSku],
FROM Member m
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY wl.MemberID ORDER BY wli.Price DESC) AS rank, wl.MemberID, wli.SKU
                       FROM WishListItem wli
                            INNER JOIN WishList wl ON wli.WishListID = wl.ID) T1) w ON w.MemberID = m.ID
```

My question is, is there a better way to get the top first and second records for each user? If not, is there a way I can optimize this query? Ideally, if I can restirct the number of tiems pulled back from the ranking query (the one with the DENSE_RANK()) that will help me out. I wanted to do something like WHERE DENDS_RANK() <= 2, but that's not possible, and doing it outside of the brackets defeats the purpose of the soultion.

Also, this is just part of the query. I actually have even more left joins across more tables that have just as many items, and I need to get the top 1 and 2 records for each user.

And this needs to be done in one query, or as much as possible in one because I'm throwing it in a data table. I can also reduce the number of records, ie. TOP 1000, and break up the query, but I will need to be able to continue from where I left off... also, I did try TOP 1000, and after 10 minutes, I cancelled the query because I need to get all 9 million records out.

Comment: do you have indexes in any of the tables?

Comment: yes, the tables are fully indexed. I noticed that I can't even do a straight SELECT * FROM member without SQL running out of memory because there are too many records.

Comment: try to update the index statistics for a start

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your design, why is price in the wishlist table, and SKU in WLI? I'd expect Member <- WishList <- WishlistItem -> Product or something to that extent. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: fixed. I re-wrote the code to pull it out from the large query.

Comment: and I'm not too sure why the price and stuff is in there, the database was inherited from another company.

Comment: I would definitely try to filter your rank outside of the definition of your derived table T1 (`WHERE rank<=2`) and see if it makes a difference

Comment: There are parts missing from your query; it makes no sense for joining the `Member` table, as it doesn't participate in the query in any way...

Comment: Run the inner SELECT * (aliased by T1) part by itself. Does it run fast? That query is really not too bad... if it is slow, your server might just be too slow for your needs :(. The system will likely merge or hash join since you are processing so many rows. Consider creating covering indexes on the columns used by the query. Post the query plan by issuing SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON before running for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd grab a relatively small subset of the data, stick it in a table variable, and run the query off that instead of the main (and likely very "busy") tables:

```
DECLARE @Member TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    -- add necessary columns to this definition.
)

INSERT INTO @Member (field1, field2...)
SELECT field1, field2  -- etc. 
FROM YourTables
WHERE SomeCriteria = Whatever
```

Make sure that the WHERE clause defines a narrower subset of data than your production tables. If performance still suffers, you could create table variables for the other tables you're joining, then use those in the final query.